# How to fix apache proxy timing out in Docker?

Tags: apache-http-server, docker

I'm trying to configure a basic HTTP proxy with Apache in Docker, but when I try to connect to the proxy, I get a timeout.

Trace:

```
$ docker run -d -p 8080:8080 mcandre/docker-apache-proxy:latest
fa627d9c103f69120ff39232db73fc19d98a4b75279bdc0ca951ba8df88dfd7b

$ http_proxy=http://10.0.75.0 curl http://icanhazip.com
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.0.75.0 port 1080: Timed out
```

No errors appear in `/var/log/apache2/errors.log`.

However, neither do any access entries appear in `/var/log/apache2/access.log`. Does this mean that the Apache proxy configuration is missing something to actually connect things up?

Configuration:

https://github.com/mcandre/docker-apache-proxy

Answer (score 0):

Changed several parts of the configuration and got a working http proxy up!

https://github.com/mcandre/docker-apache-proxy/commit/eac666fcfe2dd6f0901a8108a632053b1ce0334b

- Adjusted the proxy address (works in Windows, for now)
- Replaced Alpine base with Debian base
- Moved virtual host into main Apache configuration.
- Specify hostname via docker-compose.
- Wait for Apache to come up before using Apache.
- Replace curl with wget, which handles HTTP and HTTPS proxies better